# How do I disable a document in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

A similar question was asked: [how-do-i-disable-an-add-in-in-word](https://superuser.com/questions/17557/how-do-i-disable-an-add-in-in-word)

However, I want to know how to disable a *document*. In my experience, I have had to enable documents which have been disabled (I don't know how they became disabled however).

Edit 6/8: A disabled document will show up in the Disabled Items list just like a disabled add-in would. I have seen this happen several times over the years, however have not found a way to consistently recreate it.

Comment: Please elaborate what do you mean by "disabled document". You couldn't open it with Word, or what?

Comment: Do you mean delete a document or make a document write protected? Password required or not? Need more info.

Comment: See my edits please.